# Order of Arguments in Curried Scala Functions

Tags: scala, currying

In Scala, I could generate a curried function like so:

```
def multiply(m: Int)(n: Int): Int = (m + 1) * (n + 2)
```

If I wanted, I could generate a new function, by filling that first parameter, like so:

```
val timesTwo = multiply(1) _
```

But what is the syntax for replacing the second argument, instead of the first?

```
val timesThree = multiply _ (1)  // Incorrect Syntax
```

More importantly, why is there not a direct parallel to `multiply(1) _`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
val timesThree = multiply(_: Int)(1)
```

or

```
val timesThree = (x: Int) => multiply(x)(1)
```

Comment: I like `multiply(_: Int)(1)`. Thanks! But why is the syntax not more parallel with `multiply(1) _`?

Comment: See section 6.7 of the Scala Reference (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf). The _ in `multiply(1) _` isn't a placeholder for anonymous function parameters like it is in `multiply(_: Int), but rather a special syntax for forcing conversion of methods to functions ("eta-expansion"). As for why the explicit types are needed, I have no idea.